# Bluetooth scanner device receive data in React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

I want to make in React Native a app that connects to a bluetooth scanner device, and receive data from it (barcodes id) after the scanned was made. It is possible? What I need to use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan barcodes directly from your phone and there are libraries that support such functionality for react native. However if using a bluetooth scanner device is a requirement then you have two options you can choose from -

1. Get access to bluetooth functionality through Native Modules
2. Use an existing library that provides bluetooth capabilities to react-native. A really good option can be this library https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

In general it is possible to achieve what you need

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the answer! My client also wants to implement infrared scanning, so I asked if it would be possible to connect that device to the phone.